# Trapping SIGINT (and other signals) on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, signals

Why this simple script:

```
#! perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
$| = 1;

my $LOCKFILE = "$0.lock";

sub mklock {
    open my $lf, ">", $LOCKFILE;
    print $lf $$;
    close $lf;
}

sub rmlock { unlink $LOCKFILE; }

sub clean_exit { rmlock;  exit 0; }

sub work {
    print "working...";
    sleep 10;
    # although `sleep 1 foreach (1..10);`
    # *does* interrupt---between `sleep`s--see my answer
    print "done.\n"
}

$SIG{INT} = "clean_exit";

mklock;
work;
rmlock;
```

works on Debian but not on Windows?

- on Windows, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is ignored when this script is working
- on Debian, clean exit is performed as expected
- with `$SIG{INT} = \&clean_exit;`, the behavior seems the same
- (if I do the same with `SIGHUP` (`$SIG{HUP} = "clean_exit";`), window is closed but clean exit is not performed anyway)

(Well, I admit that it's Strawberry `perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread` on Windows 7 amd64 -vs- `perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi` on the Debian 6.0.4 box, but I doubt it matters for such basic stuff. **Edit:** I just checked it on similar box with ActiveState perl 5.12 and it's the same, so apparently the problem is not isolated to Strawberry.)

I know [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#System-Interaction) says it clear,

> Don't count on signals or %SIG for anything.

but there must be a way... (Plus, I would like to understand.)

So what should be done differently?

Comment: very strange - Ctrl-C works for me in both a cygwin terminal and the standard cmd window (both instances of perl are cygwin)

Comment: @Petesh On my box, it works OK in Cygwin. (Unfortunately Cygwin won't work for my *actual* problem as I need to deploy my scripts on some unsuspecting Windows machines with Strawberry. And then do a lot of very Windows-ish things :))

Comment: see my answer - strawberry obeys windows conventions, which means that Alt+Break works, but Ctrl+C doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding some more `print`ing, I found out that actually, the code *does* work, except that it does not interrupt during `sleep`.

So just changing `sleep 60` to more "realistic" `sleep 1 foreach (1..10);` brings much more acceptable behavior.

It still does work differently on Windows than on *nix, of course.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`sigtrap`](http://perldoc.perl.org/sigtrap.html) pragma:

```
use sigtrap 'handler', \&cleanup, 'normal-signals';
```

This will call the method `cleanup` when a signal is caught and passes the signal identification as parameter.

Comment: That line as is (with cleanup replaced with clean_exit) causes the script to terminate under strawberry perl

Comment: @Petesh: can't test with strawberry, but works fine with ActiveState. The `cleanup` function gets also called during normal termination of the script...

Comment: This is great as it adds more debugging potential. (You can log what happened...) However, on Win, it does not work with HUP when I close cmd.exe window :/

Answer (score 1):

Obeying unix line discipline in a DOS application is a luxury, not a right.

It does obey `Ctrl+Break`, which is the windows equivalent of Ctrl+C

**Edit** Changed to Ctrl+Break - this is what I get for using a mac keyboard.

For the purposes of testing interrupt handling, you should use the following loop in your work sub, as otherwise it waits until the entire sleep has completed before triggering handler:

```
sub work {
    print "working...";
    my $i = 0;
    while ($i < 10) {
       sleep(1);
       $i--;
    }
    say "done."
}
```

This way it is more easily able to detect the keypress - the interrupt handling is not being detected while the sleep is in progress.

Color me confused - the INT handler is working now!

**Edit** The raw source code for perl claims that it should support HUP as the close window event, but The event doesn't seem to be delivered when I click on the close of a CMD window

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. However, it's perfectly confusing that if you *don't* touch `%SIG`, you get `working...Terminating on signal SIGINT(2)` on Ctrl+C. (But then again, what's not confusing about DOS...?)

Comment: Actually, Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Break have been DOS concepts "for ever".